# Http to Https URL rewriting

Tags: asp.net, http, https, iis-8.5

My requirement is straight forward. i have `Http://abc` need to make it `Https://abc` . I have added the folowing code in web.config. i.e. added new rule in IIS. 
I have folowwed the URL rewriting module in IIS.

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="http to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^off$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

But still it doesn't work for me. Help me out.

Comment: Have you installed the IIS rewrite module?

Comment: Yes. already done, from there added the new rule. The code is belongs to new rule itself.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using is very similar to what I use in production except that I use `redirectType="Permanent"` and I happen to use a hard coded domain name to ensure a canonical domain and I use `{R:1}` for the path and query but I think using `{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}` as you are should work however you may need a slash between the two.

Give this a try:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="http to https" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^off$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks Ron, but i have tried this as well. Its not working. I have got it in another way. I have created a demo website in IIS. Gave the same DNS name (i.e.abc from  Http://abc) . then added a single Html page, where the code is with 

`function redirecttoHttps()
{

var httpsUrl="https://abc";
window.location=httpsUrl;
}
redirecttoHttps();`

Thus when user type Http://abc then the Script inside the Html page will push it to Https://abc.

Not sure if its recommended ornot. Because ultimately in Https://abc site user validation is happening. Only the thing we are doing is redirect.

Comment: That's odd, one more thing you can try is changing `url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"` to `url="https://yourDomainHere.com/{R:1}"` which is actually how my site is configured.